# This div's border is a floating line instead of an actual border

Tags: html, css, border

I might be missing something basic.  It's so simple:

```css
.items {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 25px 30px 0px 0px;
}

.langswitch {
  border: 3px solid #86D1DA;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="langswitch">
  <div class="items">Italiano</div>
</a>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4pcmvmg/)

Moving the class from the anchor to the div will make it (the border) disappear all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `<a>` tag inside the `<div>` rather than the other way around.

```css
.items{
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 25px 30px 0px 0px ;
}

.langswitch{
  border: 3px solid #86D1DA;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items"><a href="#" class="langswitch">Italiano</a></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you going to explain your answer, or are you just going to treat it as a game of spot-the-difference?

Comment: This worked. Can you explain why this is better practice?

Answer (score 3):

Well, your `<a class="lamgswitch">` does not have any content... The `float: left;` makes the `<div class="items">`float out of it...

So try to remove it, and replace it with `display: inline-block;`, as the `div` is a block component, and you placed it inside an inline component (`a`)...

```css
.items {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 25px 30px 0px 0px;
}

.langswitch {
  border: 3px solid #86D1DA;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="langswitch">
  <div class="items">Italiano</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, placing the `<a>` inside the `<div>` is the semantically correct way to do this as described in the other answer.

If you really HAVE to do it this way, you need to change the display of the `<a>` tag from `inline` to `inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. Why is this better practice? I thought it should be the same.